# Amazon Web Service - Communicating with RDS database from front-end client

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

To keep it simple, I'm hosting a single-page static website using the Amazon S3 service, however I want to include a field that allows users to input their e-mail addresses and submit it. This e-mail should then be added to my database. I am using a MySQL database from the Amazon RDS service. Also, since this is a static webpage, I do not have a back-end running.

I'm wondering what is the architecturally best way to do this write to the database? Should I add javascript to the front-end to write the e-mails to the database? Would this expose the database access keys to the public? Should I instead use Amazon Lambda to do the writes to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**
It is possible and Amazon provides a Javascript SDK to run on client to connect to back end services.
While it is possible, I would still suggest to use lambda to do this job

Amazon offers SDK for Javascript in the browser ([doc](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/sdk-for-browser/)) it has some [good examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html) to work for example with DynamoDB

> The following example puts an item in a DynamoDB table and then reads
>   it back using the hash key.
>
> ```
> var table = new AWS.DynamoDB({params: {TableName: 'MY_TABLE'}});
> var key = 'UNIQUE_KEY_ID';
>
> // Write the item to the table
> var itemParams = {Item: {id: {S: key}, data: {S: 'data'}}};
> table.putItem(itemParams, function() {
>   // Read the item from the table
>   table.getItem({Key: {id: {S: key}}}, function(err, data) {
>     console.log(data.Item); // print the item data
>   });
> });
> ```

You can use those Javascript methods from any site (even static sites running on S3) you would just need to add the library to your pages

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.2.28.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How does this allow him to write the db without exposing his access information? Wouldn't he need to store it somewhere for the javascript code to read, so it knows where to go and that the code has access to the db?

Comment: you can check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html - clearly hard coded the credentials is not the right ways, you can use cognito

Answer (score 1):

As far As I know, javascript can't process your request to server side.

you will be required server side components to process the request.